# Update multiple rows with one query using a different rows value

Tags: mysql

I didn't know how to clearly title this.

After joining a table on itself using shared_id I get the following data.

```
a.id   | a.shared_id | a.key     | a.value         | b.id   | b.shared_id | b.key       | b.value
198131 | 6044        | unique-id | E15SJOEMGRMH013 | 198281 |6044         | _unique_id  |
```

This is the result from:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE key='unique-id') AS a
JOIN
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE key='_unique_id') AS b
ON a.shared_id = b.shared_id
WHERE a.value!='' AND a.value!=b.value AND a.key='unique-id'
;
```

What I need is an update statement that will set b.value to a.values value.So in this 1 row example I want b.value to be `E15SJOEMGRMH013`.

Now remember a.id and b.id are NOT the same as the keys are called something slightly different but they should hold the same value. There are several hundred rows so I would like to do this in one update query.

Comment: Please show what you tried. You basically take your join, replace the `SELECT <columns> FROM <tablename> b` with `UPDATE <tablename> `, and add `SET b.value = a.value` at the end.

Comment: @Barmar query added. im not sure how to make it an update statement because of the multiple rows with different ids and yet the same shared_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the sub-queries, and your use of them is probably why you couldn't figure out the corresponding `UPDATE` query.

```
UPDATE table1 AS a
JOIN table1 AS b ON a.shared_id = b.shared_id
SET b.value = a.value
WHERE a.key = 'unique-id' AND b.key = '_unique_id'
    AND a.value != ''
```

The `SELECT` should be simply:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS a
JOIN table1 AS b ON a.shared_id = b.shared_id AND a.value != b.value
WHERE a.key = 'unique-id' AND b.key = '_unique_id'
    AND a.value != ''
```

You don't need the `a.value != b.value` clause in the `UPDATE` -- if they're the same, the `UPDATE` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Wow yes this is much easier then the way I built it out I see my logic error now. Thanks!